# make Delphi XE 8 editor color more clear

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

porting a code from Delphi XE 5 to XE 8 I noticed the colors of the font inside XE8 are not clear like in XE5 IDE although I use the same font. The color appear more clear if I choose white background but if I choose black background (which I want) the colors seems dimmed. is there a setting or something I can use to increase contrast or clarity of XE8 editor colors ?

screenshot of XE5 colors:

[image]

Screenshot of of XE8 colors:

[image]

Comment: Try the [Delphi IDE Theme Editor](https://github.com/rruz/delphi-ide-theme-editor)

Comment: I'm not sure if the actual text area is affected, by try disabling Castalia: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520761/how-can-i-disable-castalia-in-xe8

Comment: but** I need to stop typing when I'm drunk...

Comment: I'd be more concerned by the fact that the yellow colour is coming out white. Or are you not comparing like with like?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hi, My problem that any color look dimmed or faint on a dark background (this is not a problem on light background) and once I check the windows option "use windows xp style dpi scaling" all the colors become sharp and clear but Delphi IDE controls get wrong dimensions.

Comment: I voted to close this question because you are asking why two things that are patently different, are different. I suggest that you need to be a little more controlled in your comparisons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the  syntax highlighting  colors  from the `Tools -> Options ->Editor Options -> Color` Menu or if you prefear you can use one the themes included in the [Delphi IDE Theme Editor](https://github.com/rruz/delphi-ide-theme-editor)

Comment: thanks, I already tried this nice app but the colors appear more clear if I choose white background but if I choose black background (which I want) the colors seems so dimmed.

Comment: There is a lot of themes with dark backgrounds, so just try with another one.

Comment: tried all the dark background make foreground colors so dimmed.

Comment: @Wel Have you tried manually setting your colors as suggested?

Comment: @JerryDodge yes no luck, also disabled castalia

Comment: When I use option "use windows xp style dpi scaling" the color become more clear but the Delphi IDE controls get ruined

Comment: If I compare the two pictures, I see different colours and also a different font. Try setting all of those manually, also the different font. It is very well possible to get the appearance of the XE5 picture.

Answer (score 0):

A guy from i think Germany still developing this dark theme to xe8 [LINK](https://github.com/RWarnecke/Delphi-Editor-Theme/tree/master/dark). Thanks to him
[image]