# How to stop creating .stat file in Delphi 10 Seattle IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

When I open and use Delphi project files in `RAD Studio 10 Seattle` IDE.  It always create .stat files.  Is there a way to stop creating the files?

Comment: I complained about this issue in XE8. It's related to the Castalia statistics collection, which is moronic (who cares how many minutes and seconds I spent in the Code Editor vs. the debugger vs. the form designer?). It appears that even though they integrated the Castalia functionality, they failed to turn off the stats collecting code.

Comment: I disabled Castalia - it's of no use to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520761/how-can-i-disable-castalia-in-xe8

Comment: They didn't fail to turn off the stats collecting code. You can view the statistics using View->Project Statistics.

Comment: Delphi 10 Seattle IDE doesn't seems to have the castalia package install but .stat files keep show up.

Comment: Castalia is still there. It's what is behind the colour coded block lines drawn in the ide

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Remove what? Castalia or the file?

Comment: Remove or disable castalia package? so the IDE stop creating .stat file.

Answer (score 4):

Open project's properties, go to *Build Events* and in the *Post-build events* enter the following command:

```
del /q "$(INPUTDIR)$(INPUTNAME).stat"
```

or

```
if exist "$(INPUTDIR)$(INPUTNAME).stat" del /q "$(INPUTDIR)$(INPUTNAME).stat"
```