# The IDE hangs when "|" is present in the source code. Is it a bug in Delphi XE8?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Whenever I type a "|" (vertical bar) in source editor, the Delphi IDE starts to hang.

I tried to add the "|" in my source code via notepad before opening my project with Delphi then it seems that the IDE is hanging while opening the project.

Example 1 (This will work):

```
procedure TForm8.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if 1 = 1 then
    ShowMessage('True');
end;
```

Example 2 (This will not work):

```
procedure TForm8.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if 1 = 1 then || "1" = "1" then //Whenever I start typing the "|", the IDE starts to hang.
    ShowMessage('True');
end;
```

> Note: The Delphi IDE is not hanging with my project after I removed the "|" (vertical bar) in my source code through notepad (before opening the project with Delphi).

Comment: | is not an operator in Delphi. It may be a bug, but your code is invalid. Report the bug to EMBT; we can't fix it here. Other than to tell you to not try and use | as an operator in Delphi source code, of course. The proper operator for *or* is `or`, as in `if (1 = 1) or ("1" = "1") then`.

Comment: @Ken It's a Castalia bug. It affects you even if you type | accidentally.

Comment: @David: Yes, I can see that from Stefan's answer. However, this poster said *Whenever I type* and *I tried to add the "I" in my source code via notepad*, which leads me to believe that the OP was trying to use the pipe as the OR operator, which is why I explained the difference.

Comment: @Ken I assumed that the user was just trying to debug the problem and work out whether it affected just entry, or parsing.

Comment: @David: OK. I assumed that the user meant the words that he/she typed. :-)

Comment: @Ken I assumed that too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is [a bug](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10458) and unfortunately only fixed [in the subscription update](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/44470).

You need to [turn off Castalia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29523187/587106) if you don't have that update.

Comment: Not fixed in the non-subscription update? Shame on Embarcadero.

Comment: That's rough. I wasn't even aware that there was a difference in updates between purchases of Delphi and subscribers.

Comment: @Graymatter This difference was introduced with XE8. If you don't have active subscription you cannot count on getting bug fixes. See [XE8 fix list](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/44470) and notice the difference between General update and Subscription update list.

Comment: @Graymatter What's more, even if you buy the software after the fix has been issued to subscribers, Emba still ship the defective version to you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and if you upgrade to Seattle without buying subscription, you will also receive XE8 license without full Update pack.